# get user data from firebase database flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

hello everyone I'm trying to extract the data of a single user who has logged in but absolutely nothing is printed on the console or on the screen, while if I try to print all the data of all the users it works perfectly why? i hope you can help me

```
 Future<void> ProfileData() async {
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('utenti')
    .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
    .snapshots()
    .listen((DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.exists) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
       
        setState(() {
          Nome = data["Nome"];
          Cognome = data["Cognome"];
          Indirizzo = data["Indirizzo"];
          Email = data["email"];
        });
      } else {
        print('Nessun documento trovato per l\'utente corrente.');
      }
    });
  final allUsersSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('utenti').get();
  final allUsersData = allUsersSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();
  print('Dati di tutti gli utenti: $allUsersData');
}
```

this is what the console prints me for the two print:

```
flutter: Nessun documento trovato per l'utente corrente //EN No documents found for the current user. 
flutter: Dati di tutti gli utenti //EN : All user data : [{email: xxxxxxx, Nome: xxxxxx, Indirizzo: xxxxxx, Cognome: xxxxxx}, {email: xxxxxxx, Nome: xxxxxxx, Indirizzo: xxxxxx, Cognome: xxxxxx}, {email: xxxxxxxx, Nome: xxxxxxx, Indirizzo: xxxxxxx, , Cognome: xxxxxxxx}, {email: xxxxxxxx, Nome: xxxxxx, Indirizzo: xxxxxx, Cognome: xxxxxxx}, { email: xxxxxxxxx, Nome: xxxxxxx, Indirizzo: xxxxxxx,  Cognome: xxxxxxx}, {email: xxxxxxxx, Nome: xxxxxxx, Indirizzo: xxxxxxxx,  Cognome: xxxxxxxx}]
```

**the x censors but the data is there and also that of the current user but it is not shown in the previous function and in fact it says "No documents found for the current user. " .
I added the slashes with "En" so that everyone can understand it in English.
i hope you can help me**

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<void> ProfileData() async {

    DocumentReference docRef = await 
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("utenti")
   .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);

    try{
        DocumentSnapshot doc= await docRef.get();
        DataType Nome = doc.get("Nome");
        DataType Cognome = doc.get("Cognome");
        DataType Indirizzo = doc.get("Indirizzo");
        DataType Email = doc.get("email");

        Map<String,dynamic> data = {
         "Nome":Nome,
         "Cognome":Cognome,
         "Indirizzo":Indirizzo,
         "Email":Email
        };
    }
    catch(e){
        print('Nessun documento trovato per l\'utente corrente.');
    }
final allUsersSnapshot = await 
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('utenti').get()
final allUsersData = allUsersSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => 
doc.data()).toList();
print('Dati di tutti gli utenti: $allUsersData');
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I know you're struggling to write it well but I don't quite understand what to replace precisely I know I'm asking a lot but could you take the code you showed me and replace it with what I have in the question??

Comment: @sams let me know if you run into any issues

Comment: yeah  small update doesn't work i don't know why but the print of the uid in console is shown but unfortunately it doesn't show anything in app

Comment: Inside the try block can you try and add in the code print(Nome); after it is defined just to see if it is able to retrieve the user's data? you can add this anywhere in the try block after "Nome" is defined

Comment: it definitely doesn't show anything in the app or in the console